# How to get all the links of a list inside a div?

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I have a code with the following DOM Tree:

```
<div id="blogPagination">
    <div class="pagination">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="/2" >1</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="/3" >2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to reach the href of my  tag. I can't reach it with anything I tried.

What's the best way to reach it with jQuery ?

I tried:

> `console.log($('#blogPagination div ul > li a ').attr("href"));`
>
> `console.log($('#blogPagination > a ').attr("href"));`
>
> `$('#blogPagination').children('a')`
>
> `console.log($('#blogPagination div ul li a').attr("href"));`

without luck ..

Thanks

EDIT:

After nbrooks's answer, here is what I tried so far:

```
function bindPagination() {
    
    console.log("bind");

    $(function() {
        var links = $("#blogPagination ul a").map(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
            return this.href;
        }).get();
        console.log(links);
});
```

EDIT 2 :

Considering Syfaro's answer, I've also tried :

```
$('#blogPagination').find('a').each(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Without luck.

EDIT 3 :
I'd like to give more details concerning this function that may have a significant impact after all:

to load this pagination, I'm using Ajax and handlebars wrapped into a document ready function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    
    // Get the customer service stats
    var Content = {

    init: function() {

            /* this.getHomePosts(); */
            this.getBlogPosts();
        },

    getBlogPosts: function(offset) {
        if(offset == undefined){
            offset = 0;
        }
        // GET the events with JSON
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: {},
            url: site_url+"/main/blog/"+offset,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(results) {
                posts = results["posts"].map(function (blogContent) {
                    if( blogContent.picture != '' ) {
                        return {
                            Title: blogContent.title ,
                            Picture: Content.urlPostPic + blogContent.picture ,
                            Video: '' ,
                            Text: blogContent.text ,
                            Datetime: blogContent.datetime ,
                        }
                    } else {
                        return {
                            Title: blogContent.title ,
                            Picture: '' ,
                            Video: blogContent.video ,
                            Text: blogContent.text ,
                            Datetime: blogContent.datetime ,
                        }
                    }
                });

                pagination = {pagination: results["pagination"]};

                var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#templateBlog').html() );
                $('#blogPosts').append( template(posts) );

                var template = Handlebars.compile( $('#templatePagi').html() );
                $('#blogPagination').append( template(pagination) );
                                    // Here we call bindPagination <===
                bindPagination();
            }
        });
    },

};

Content.init();
```

You can see in the get BlogPosts function that I call BindPagination which is supposed to be this function, to prevent default behavior and call the content depending of the offset (pagination system)

```
function bindPagination() {
    
    console.log("bind");

    
    var links = $("#blogPagination ul a").map(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return this.href;
    }).get();
    console.log(links);

    $('#blogPagination').find('a').each(function(e) {
        console.log("clicked !");
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log($(this).attr('href'));

     //    var attr = this.attr();
        // var id = attr.replace("/","");

        // $('#blogPosts').empty();
        // $('#blogPagination').empty();
        // Content.getBlogPosts(id);
    });
}
});
```

the last }); stand for the end of the document ready.

Comment: And you included jQuery and remembered document ready etc. as at least a few of those should work -> http://jsfiddle.net/a4BKA/

Comment: yes I did, it is wrapped into a document ready

Comment: Check your JavaScript console to see if there are any error messages logged

Comment: I don't have any error message but the one telling me there is a 404 error when clicking on the link (but this is normal)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

```
$('#blogPagination').find('a').attr('href');
```

This should find all `a` elements in the specified area, the get the `href` of them, assuming that you've already got jQuery and all that good stuff set up.

If you have multiple `a` elements, you could do something like this:

```
$('#blogPagination').find('a').each(function() {
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This will print out each `href` of each `a` in that `div`.

If you need to prevent the link from changing the page, you need to add a click handler to the `a` elements.

```
$('#blogPagination').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This will prevent the user from being taken to the link, and get the `href` of the link when clicked.

Is this what you want?

Comment: That does assume there's only one `a` (I know, in the demo there *is* only one, but that may be a simplification).

Comment: @DavidThomas I added more to my answer should you have multiple `a`s.

Comment: The big question being; Why would this work and not any of the snippets the OP has already tried ?

Comment: Yes, I do suppose that would be the question. I'd imagine that it has something to do with jQuery, but as I stated in my answer, my answer assumed that jQuery was properly loaded.

Comment: Thank you but I can't have it done, please see the edits. Thanks

Comment: @MilesM. so you want to prevent the user from going to the page when the link is clicked, and get the `href`? I updated my answer to that. You only need the new bit if you only need it to do that.

Comment: I think the problem was coming from the fact I had multiples events listing attached to the same object ...

Answer (score 8):

The function you are likely looking for is [`map`](http://api.jquery.com/map). This allows you to take a given jQuery collection and transform it by taking a specific property of each object and making that the element in the resulting collection.

To collect all the href's in your array:

```
$(function() {
    var links = $("#blogPagination ul a").map(function() {
        return this.href;
    }).get();
    console.log(links);
});
```

[***jsFiddle Demo***](http://jsfiddle.net/vMdYR/)

*Note:* The [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector) (`el1 > el2`) only works when `el2` is, well, a direct descendant of `el1`. So at least one of your examples would have failed because you didn't match that with your DOM tree. However, `console.log($('#blogPagination div ul > li a ').attr("href"));` would work to find the href of (only) the very first anchor tag, assuming you wrapped it in a DOM-ready handler `$(function() { ... });`.

The [`children`](http://api.jquery.com/children) method is similar, in that it will only find direct descendants (children), and not grandchildren, etc. If you want to find *all* descendants down the DOM tree of a particular element, use [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) instead.

Comment: Thank you but I can't have it done, please see the edits. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The Vanilla Javascript Solution

```
document.querySelectorAll("div #blogPagination a").forEach((item)=>console.log(item.href));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your console - as I suspect there is either a conflict or javascript error that is causing the jQuery not to work.

Your statements are correct and should select the element you require.

Comment: there is no error in my console and I can see the console.log("bind");

Answer (score 0):

The Vannila Javascript Solution

```
Array.prototype.map.call(document.querySelectorAll(".myselectorAreaofLinks"), function (e) {
  return e.getAttribute('href');
});
```