# Save a <li> tag in a var and then use it in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div class="ranges">
  <ul>
        <li>A</li>
        <li>B</li>
        <li>C</li>
        <li>D</li>
        <li>Range</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I want to save `<li>` in a var and then use it like:

```
// lets sat li is in a var VarRange.

if(VarRange=='Range')
{
   // do something.
}
```

Comment: Have you even tried anything? This is a very VERY basic loop you want.

Comment: @RUJordan Looks like he's is treating SO as a 'do that for me' instead of Q/A. Look his profile for the questions. And of course, ppl answer wanting the +rep

Comment: no thats not a case. i am always confused with how to achieve a nested ul or anything inside some div. is it like $('ranges.li')

Comment: i want to do it my own please people help me.

Comment: @user3400389 there's this magic called google, you should try it out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175442/how-to-get-all-the-links-of-a-list-inside-a-div-with-jquery

Comment: @RUJordan Good answer on that one, good explanation. @user3400389 I'll give you the start then. try make the check by yourself. `$('.ranges ul li').each(function(index, element){ /*do your checks here, using element and index*/ });`

Comment: hey please explain whats index for?

Comment: @user3400389 no offense but you really need to google things. https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/ you could have solved this whole question with 2 searches

Comment: Then the index is the position of the elements found with the selector.  Therefore, inside the .each, the first time will be index 0 is <li>A</li>., see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$('div.ranges ul li').each(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='Range')
    {
        $(this).css('color','red');
    }
});
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/9NHL9/1/)

It checks each `<li>` to see if it contains "Range". If it does, it colors it in red.

Comment: thankyou for a simple solution. i was doing ranges.li.