# Wait for dynamic content to load before gathering links

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

We have a third party widget on our site. This widget displays dynamically-created content.

I would like to track clicks to their content via Google Analytics, but as their tech support said, due to the fact that the content is dynamically-generated, "it is difficult to add an event listener to these links."

They suggest "waiting for this product content widget content to load, then using jQuery to get all the links..."

Now, I believe I know how to gather the links once they load, but does anyone have any idea how I can "wait for the content to load?"

Using info from @cmorrissey, I have come up with the following:

```
$('p.link-track').ready(function(){
 $('p.link-track').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  ga('send', 'event', 'link-track', 'click'); 
 });
});
```

But that did not work. Per [How to get all the links of a list inside a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175442/how-to-get-all-the-links-of-a-list-inside-a-div-with-jquery) I have also tried:

```
$('p.link-track').ready(function(){
 $('p.link-track').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
  ga('send', 'event', 'link-track', 'click'); 
 });
});
```

I have also tried `$(document).ready(function(){` in place of 
`$('p.avantlink-track').ready(function(){`

Answer (score 1):

you can use jQuery `.on()` http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){ });
```