# Get collection of Href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting the below html using this code:

```
$(".ms-rtestate-field")[0];
```

and here is the return

```
<div class="ms-rtestate-field" dir=""> 
<a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a> 
<a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌​ionsEN.pdf">EN</a> 
</div>
```

How to get the hrefs of all the anchors in the div where some divs may list many anchors? trying this one but not good

```
$(".ms-rtestate-field")[0].attr(""href);
```

Comment: Only first and second ?

Comment: May be the whole collection please in case if I have 5 href within that div

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to get all the links of a list inside a div with jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18175442/how-to-get-all-the-links-of-a-list-inside-a-div-with-jquery)

Answer (score 3):

Create an array and add hrefs to it.

```
var hrefs = [];

$(".ms-rtestate-field a").each(function(){
  hrefs.push($(this).attr("href"));
});
```

Now you can access them like:

```
for(var i=0;i<hrefs.length;i++)
    alert(hrefs[i]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".ms-rtestate-field a").each(function(){
var href = $(this).attr("href");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to get the First href and second href ?

make it

```
var firstHREF = $(".ms-rtestate-field a:eq(0)").attr("href");
var secondHREF = $(".ms-rtestate-field a:eq(1)").attr("href");
```

You need to go one level below to the specific anchor `a` based on its index using `eq` selector.

If you want the array of hrefs then simply

```
var hrefs = [];
$(".ms-rtestate-field a").each(function(){
  hrefs.push( $(this).attr( "href" ) );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use [`.map`](http://api.jquery.com/map/), *Pass each element in the current matched set through a function, producing a new jQuery object containing the return values.*

[**Array.from()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) method creates a new Array instance from an array-like or iterable object.

```js
var href = $('.ms-rtestate-field').find('a[href]').map(function() {
  return this.href;
}).get();
console.log(href);
//OR
var href = Array.from($('.ms-rtestate-field').find('a[href]')).map(function(elem) {
  return elem.href;
});
console.log(href);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ms-rtestate-field" dir="">
  <a href="/DE/Company/OurOrganisation/ActionsDE.pdf">DE</a> 
  <a href="/EN/Company/OurOrganisation/Act‌ionsEN.pdf">EN</a> 
</div>
```